# How to provide proof for termination in Agda?

Tags: agda, induction, termination

I am trying to write an integer division function from scratch in agda2 (as of 2.6.3):

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ

{-# BUILTIN NATURAL ℕ #-}

_∸_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
_∸_ m n = {}0

div : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
div m n with m ∸ n 
...     | 0  = 0
...     | x = suc (div x n)
```

The basic idea is to use the monus function ∸ (integer minus) to subtract `n` from `m` until the difference is zero. But when loading the file, there is an error:

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  div
Problematic calls:
  div m n | m ∸ n
  div x n
```

I can see that the error happens because agda has no way to tell if the monus function is decreasing until it reaches zero (i.e. m ∸ n < m unless m is 0).

My questions are:

*1. How do I provide a proof to agda that m ∸ n is less than m, and the recursion is decreasing on the first argument?*

*2. Is it OK if the argument is decreasing only before reaching the base case (zero here)?*

Note: I looked at the [documentation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.4.3/language/termination-checking.html), which only says that one can use the following pragmas to basically ignore the termination check.

`TERMINATING` and `NON_TERMINATING`

But I'd like to provide a proof rather than dictate to agda that monus is decreasing (since what the human asserts could be wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three possible approaches:

1. Use a different algorithm, like [division in stdlib](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Base.html#6109), see `div-helper`.
2. Use the well-founded induction library. There are many online resources with examples, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704076/7083401.
3. Use a natural number parameter as the indicator of termination, and make its initial value big enough. For instance, I can define it with an auxiliary parameter `k`, where the initial value of `k` is big enough, and `k` gets smaller as the recursion proceeds:

```
div' : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
div' zero m n = 0
div' (suc k) m n with m ∸ n
...     | 0  = 0
...     | x = suc (div' k x n)

div : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
div m n = div' m m n
```